# AJAX Discord api invalid request origin

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I want to create own discord client using this example code to log in:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login',
    data: '{ "email": "example@mail.com", "password" : "12345678"}',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.status_code);
    }
}).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
     var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
     console.error( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

It is JSON request in browser

> { "email": "example@mail.com", "password" : "12345678"}

It is JSON response in browser

> {"message": "Invalid request origin", "code": 50067}

and error

> Request Failed: error, Bad Request

What is the reason of such results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try adding the origin header to your request.
Discord uses it to make sure requests are coming from the real client

`headers: { origin: 'https://discord.com' }`

Edit: you might also want to switch to API version 9 or 10 since version 6 is depricated.